# What aircraft is in The Do’s music video?

Tags: aircraft-identification

There is a band call The Do, in one of their videos there is a plane with a strange configuration of turbines, it looks like a version of a 747.

You can find the video on Youtube "[The Dø - Despair, Hangover & Ecstasy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fITx45PodIM)"

Does anyone know what plane it is?

Comment: I can't edit this question because it has a pending edit, but if it hasn't already happened by the time the edit is reviewed, you can add this URL to the question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAXmgId3NTQ It's the song the question is talking about.

Answer (score 18):

This looks like [G-BDXJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-BDXJ), a modified 747 that was also featured in James Bond Casino Royale as well as other movies.

Edit: The linked wikipedia page confirms this:

> It was used as a prop in the music video of The Dø song "Despair, Hangover & Ecstasy"

Comment: This plane is now a **non-flyable** movie prop

Answer (score -1):

It is indeed a modified 747, based at Duxford and parked next to the "Top Gear" test track.

Comment: Not Duxford, it's at Dunsfold.